# What is the easiest way to sandbox an application in a *NIX environment?

Tags: linux, sandbox, unix, isolation

I have a significant number of untrusted binary applications that need to be executed on a *nix box.

I'm hoping that there might be some simple command/script (e.g. `sandbox ./app1953`) that could easily be used to isolate a single application from being able to harm or access the rest of the system (I only need access to stdin/stdout).

I'd rather not use full-blown virtual machines, as the overhead resulting from running thousands of copies of an OS is considerably larger than I'd like to consider.

Comment: what about docker?

Answer (score 4):

There is no secure, easy-to-use command line sandbox utility. Popular utilities such as Firejail can often be a cure worse than the disease, and many sandbox bypasses and privilege escalation vulnerabilities [have been found](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2017/q1/20) (and continue to be found) in it. Sandboxing an application usually requires using mandatory access controls, such as the popular [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) or [SELinux](https://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page) framework. This will generally involve customized security policies, tailored to the specific application.

I wrote a lot about Linux sandboxing in [another answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/175373/106285).

Comment: Has the situation improved with bubblewrap?  I'm quite happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

[firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com) command line utility depending on apparmor of SeLinux

```
apt install firejail
firejail --whitelist=~/Chroot bash
```

Comment: Did you even read @forest answer before posting your answer? Cause if you did why did you not expend it with addressing his comments about Firejail specifically...

Comment: To make it fast